# Target necessary frameworks in order to support mixed project types

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am currently using asp.net-core 2.1 with several .net-core 2.1 libraries. Two of the projects are based on an ef-core 2.1 library and a model library. I now need to develop a Windows service that references both of those projects, I assumed I could simply switch them to netstandard 2.0.

According to [Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/1675), this is possible, however I have the following set in the asp.net core project (using sdk 2.1.400):

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
```

but it fails to compile with:

```
NU1202 Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0 is not compatible with netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0 supports: netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1)
```

Anyone know how I can leverage the ef core and model libs in a Windows service?

Comment: "I could simply switch them to netstandard 2.0." That's not possible when they have references like `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`. Why do generic assemblies need to have such (ASP.NET Core specific) references?

Comment: Brilliant, the model library has `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />` as there are several attributes from the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` namespace. Referencing the explicit deps instead worked. Write your comment up as an answer, and thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied from the comment.

Most ASP.NET Core packages are .NET Standard 2.0 compliant, but the meta package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` is not.

So to re-target your two projects to .NET Standard 2.0, you need to remove the package reference to `.App`, and use references to the individual packages instead, like you discovered.